# Android studio RC 1 what is the new gradle files is?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to AS RC 1 am bit confused about new gradle files, and i didn't find a resource on android developer site explaining what this new files do.

1. bintaryv1.gradle.
2. installv1.gradle.
3. code_coverage.gradle.
4. gradle-mvn-push.gradle.

[image]

Comment: Above this window in the same window of the explorer, click "Android" and choose "project", it will show real structure of the srcs.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos  answer ?

Comment: Just so you can check better where those files goes